# Multiple Button Images from PHPickerViewController

Tags: swift, uikit, phpickerviewcontroller, phpicker

My View has four buttons. When you click on a button it launches the PHPickerViewController that allows a user to select an image from their device. How can I know which button was clicked so that I can set the chosen image on that specific button?

```
@objc func showImage(sender: UIButton){
    var configuration1 = PHPickerConfiguration(photoLibrary: .shared())
    configuration1.selectionLimit = 1
    configuration1.filter = .images
    let picker = PHPickerViewController(configuration: configuration1)
    picker.delegate = self
    present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
extension ProfileController: PHPickerViewControllerDelegate {
    func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        guard !results.isEmpty else {
            return
        }
        for result in results {
            result.itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) {
                [weak self]
                object, error in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    guard let self = self else {
                        return
                    }
                    if let image = object as? UIImage {

                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside your ViewController class: `var selectedButton: UIButton!`

```
@objc func showImage(sender: UIButton) {
  selectedButton = sender

  var configuration1 = PHPickerConfiguration(photoLibrary: .shared())
  // rest of your code
}
```

Then in your didFinishPicking delegate:

```
if let image = object as? UIImage {        
  selectedButton.setImage(image, for: .normal)
}
```

Comment: Much appreciated. I had decided to use a tag, but this solution is more elegant.